# Date Parse Exception in java java.text.ParseException

Tags: java, android

My date string is "Oct 17 2016 12:17PM"
and My date parsing method is:

```
public static String formatDate(String dateString) {
    String stringDate = "";
    try {
        //Mar 11 2016 2:21PM
        if (dateString != null) {
            SimpleDateFormat dt = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd yyyy hh:mma");

            Date date = dt.parse(dateString);

            // *** same for the format String below
            SimpleDateFormat dt1 = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE , hh:mm a");
            stringDate = dt1.format(date);
        }
        return stringDate;
    } catch (ParseException parseException) {
        Log.e("date format", "" + parseException.getMessage());
    }
    return stringDate;
}
```

It is working fine with english language but when i change my app language to hindi or any other i am getting an exception.

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Oct 17 2016 12:17PM" (at offset 0)
```

What i do?

Comment: Date parsing depends on language. It's a Locale problem. There's many many duplicate posts here about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need set Locale English

```
SimpleDateFormat dt = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd yyyy hh:mma", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 public class Practice {
 public static void main(String...args) {
 String day,month, finalDay;
 try {
 DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
 String  currentDateTimeString = df.format(new Date());


     //String currentDateTimeString = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date());
     SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy", Locale.US);
     Date date = format.parse(currentDateTimeString);


     SimpleDateFormat dayFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd");


     day = dayFormat.format(date);


     SimpleDateFormat monthFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM");

     month = monthFormat.format(date);
     System.out.print("My day"+ day);
     System.out.println("My month"+ month);




 } catch (Exception e) {
     System.out.println("Hello exception "+ e.getMessage());
     e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

}
}